# hide navbar elements and bring up the logout button with ejs

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

i'm doing a web project, i use html, java, css. The site is on an express server generated with express-generator with ejs template, I would like that when a user logs in (done with passport and bcrypt) he is redirected to the "home" page but instead of being there the "log in" and "subscribe" items ", there must be" logout "and an icon to log into the user profile. How can it be done? can you do it in ejs?

I tried with `<% if (isLoggedIn)` ... but it doesn't work, and I deleted the code, can you give me a practical example with some lines of code please?

```html
      <header> /*home page*/
      <div class="container">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/articoli">Articoli</a></li>
            <li><a href="/serie">Serie</a></li>
            <li><a href="/accedi">Accedi</a></li>
            <li><a href="/iscriviti">Iscriviti</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you login using passport user info is in req.user object

so you have to check with a conditional operator that there is something in req.user if there is show logout else show normal menu

```
const ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated() || res.locals.isVerified) {
    return next();
  }
  req.flash("error_msg", "please signin to view this resource");
  res.redirect("/users/emailsignin");
};
```

use above middleware to check whether logged in or not

in app.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
  next();
});
```

and in navbar

```
  <% if(isAuthenticated ) { %>
```

use above check to show hide menu

Comment: thanks, I tried but it tells me that "isAuthenticated is not defined". 
    '<header>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">

        <nav>
          <% if(isAuthenticated ) { %>
            <p>test</p>
            <% } %>'

Comment: in app.js write this    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();   next();})

Comment: now it tells me that req.isAuthenticated is not a function. where should I put the const ensureAuthenticated = ....?